# H,K be two abelian subgroups of G.Will HK be a subgroup of G?

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a non-abelian group and $H$,$K$ be two abelian subgroups of $G$.

Then will $$HK=\{hk:h\in H, k\in K\}$$ be a subgroup of $G$ ?

Comment: You mean $HK=\{hk\mid h\in H,k\in K\}$?

Comment: Yes sir. I mean it

Answer (score 4):

Think about the smallest non-Abelian group $S_3$. Is this true when $G=S_3$?

Comment: This means an abelian subgroup of a nonabelian group may not be a normal subgroup of the group. Am I right sir?

Comment: Indeed they may not @gobindachandra Can you find such a subgroup of $S_3$?

Comment: Good answer, ’cause you don’t hand the final analysis to OP.